# Как вытянуть ключ максимального значения из массива?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, jmeter

Есть массив, из него нужно вытащить максимальное значение и его ключ, если можно так выразиться. У каждого числа из массива есть свой ключ, и мне нужно вытянуть именно тот, **который связан с максимальным числом**.
При помощи регулярки вытащил числа и через jsr223 семплер нашел максимальное число.
Теперь вопрос: как извлечь ключ именно максимального числа?
Если что не пинайте, неделю как начал изучать jmeter после лр, поэтому мучаюсь.

**Сам ключ** из части массива (то, что нужно вытянуть):
dUUyTlFoUmhQMmExbCtFZ2VCY09uQT09LS1FK3lZbzJlakFUeEJoNlhCV3poRzV3PT0=--4814f46102fd5ecaf9f440be0a8925644927b3d0
Выше описал способ поиска максимального числа, **в моем случае 69**, теперь нужно как то находить ключ от максимального числа и далее применить его в реквесте.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/szHJJ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Oic4.png

**Часть массива:**

```
<div class="input radio_buttons optional challenger_order_selected"><span class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons optional" id="challenger_order_selected_duuytlfoumhqmmexbctfz2vcy09uqt09ls1fk3lzbzjlakfueejonlhcv3porzv3pt0--4814f46102fd5ecaf9f440be0a8925644927b3d0" name="challenger[order_selected]" type="radio" value="
dUUyTlFoUmhQMmExbCtFZ2VCY09uQT09LS1FK3lZbzJlakFUeEJoNlhCV3poRzV3PT0=--4814f46102fd5ecaf9f440be0a8925644927b3d0" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="challenger_order_selected_duuytlfoumhqmmexbctfz2vcy09uqt09ls1fk3lzbzjlakfueejonlhcv3porzv3pt0--4814f46102fd5ecaf9f440be0a8925644927b3d0">69</label></span></div>
```

Comment: Сори, я не сильно тестирование понимаю, а JS решение не подойдёт тут? Можешь код бросить весь или массив полностью?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, не самое изящное решение: пробежаться в [цикле](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp) по всем переменным, найти ту, у которой `maxValue_X_g2` равняется равным `maxValue_max` и сохранить куда-нибудь `maxValue_X_g1`

```
for (int i = 1; i < (vars.get('maxValue_matchNr') as int); i++) {
    if (vars.get('maxValue_' + i + '_g2').equals(vars.get('maxValue_max'))) {
        vars.put('maxKey_max', vars.get('maxValue_' + i + '_g1'))
        break;
    }
}
```

Вообще, [использовать регулярные выражения для работы с HTML - не самая лучшая идея](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), есть ненулевая вероятность что можно вытащить максимальные ключ и его значение без необходимости писать код на Groovy при помощи [XPath2 Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-xpath2-extractor-how-to-achieve-better-correlations)

Comment: разобрался, выводит корректное значение в дбг семплере, но почему то новая переменная не применяется в следующем реквесте

Comment: переменная должна быть не `${value}`, а `${maxKey_max}`

Comment: Именно ${maxKey_max} эту использовал в следующем реквесте, не работает. Хотя в дбг семплере отображается корректно

Comment: если в дебаг сэмплере отображается - должна работать, проверьте нет ли там пробелов, переносов строк и прочих непечатных символов. еще стоит убедиться что она не перезаписывается где-то еще, например вы [неправильно расположили свои постпроцессоры](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) и они выполняются после каждого сэмплера (включая дебаг сэмплер) и все переменные обнуляются (можете попробовать добавить еще один дебаг сэмплер и посмотреть что произойдет)

Comment: добавил - значение остается, используется в значении следующего реквеста, но все равно не работает, жаль нельзя прикрепить картинку

Comment: если значение переменной `${maxKey_max}` корректно передается в следующий запрос - на этом тема исчерпана. на вопрос "почему следующий запрос не работает" я ответить не могу